# Issue with Rad grid inside Rad Ajax panel row edit not firing

Tags: ajax, telerik, grid, panel

I'm facing a problem with Rad Gird inside Rad Ajax Panel

First in kept my RadGrid inside asp:panel here is works fine

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
```

When i replace asp:panel with RadAjaxpanel edit and add buttons are not working

Here is my code

```
  <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
                    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="div" runat="server"  EnableAJAX="true"  >                  
                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="rdgOpData" runat="server" CssClass="value"
                            AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="false"
                            OnNeedDataSource="rdgOpData_NeedDataSource"
                            OnItemDataBound="rdgOpData_ItemDataBound"
                            OnInsertCommand="rdgOpData_InsertCommand"
                            OnUpdateCommand="rdgOpData_UpdateCommand">

                            <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="LNK_ORIGINATEDBY_CN%%TXT_NAMELAST"
                                CommandItemSettings-AddNewRecordText="Add Opp" EditMode="EditForms"
                                InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage">
                                <EditFormSettings>
                                    <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" InsertText="Add" CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" ButtonType="PushButton">
                                    </EditColumn>
                                </EditFormSettings>
                                <Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" EditImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.gif">
                                    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
```

No firing even itemdatabound on edit button click .
Help me through this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it may happen, for best results use **RadAjaxManager**.

Add the RadAjaxManager in page, then click on **open Configuration**, the configuration is easy. 
Imagine the (One to One) case. Click on any of the control **(cause)** and map the another control **(effect)**. Just checkbox clicks.. Go ahead here's the documentation. 
[Read about RadAjaxManger here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-ajaxmanager.html)